# Best practices for save and change tokens firestore and iOS devices swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, token

How can I safely save users tokens (FCM Token and IOs devices) then save them to firestore and later change if the user changed the device?

Use `UserDefaults` or something...